# asp.net webapi 2 issues with HTTP post and parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to get this to work but wasted 2 days and still no luck.
I should admit I am not a seasoned programmer, I am a beginner and learning ASP.NET WebApi 2

I created a WebApi2 from template, and the get methods work but cannot get the HTTP post to work. Can someone help?

Here is the Controller

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : ApiController
    {
        Customer[] customers = new Customer[]
        {
            new Customer { CustName="Arvind", CustPhone="4024567892", ID=1},
            new Customer {CustName="Mike",CustPhone="4021231234", ID=2 }
        };

        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            return customers;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int ID)
        {
            var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.ID == ID);
            if (customer==null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(customer);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("PostCustomer")]
        public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer([FromBody]int ID)
        {
            var customer = customers.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.ID == ID);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(customer);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the HTML post

```
<div>
    <h2>All Customers</h2>
    <ul id="customers" />
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Search by ID</h2>
    <input type="text" id="ID" size="5" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="find();" />
    <p id="customer" />
</div>
<form method="post" action="api/customers/PostCustomer">
<div>
    <h2>Search by ID</h2>
    <input type="text" id="ID" size="5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"  />

</div>
    </form>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var uri = 'api/customers';

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#customers'));
        });
      });
});

function formatItem(item) {
  return item.CustName + ': ' + item.ID;
}

function find() {
  var id = $('#ID').val();
  $.getJSON(uri + '/' + id)
      .done(function (data) {
        $('#customer').text(formatItem(data));
      })
      .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        $('#customer').text('Error: ' + err);
      });
}
</script>
```

And finally the webconfig file

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? server response error , javascript error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set name to the input

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" size="5" />
```

to

```html
<input type="text" id="ID" name="ID" size="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**first define parameters** : for post data in a `<form>` tag , first u need define parameter's name in inputs like this :

```
<input type="text" id="ID" name="ID" size="5" />
```

**then send post request** : send post request, so you should be change `$.getJSON` in your js into `$.postJSON`.

**at the end**  i recommend you to use Postman ,[Postman](http://getpostman.com/) is an awesome REST API test client , that help you develop web api apps easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors to the current code

1. using HTML you can only send input fields via name param, ID doesn't mean anything here
2. you are sending the data to /api/customers/PostCustomer, while this is a let's say usual way in MVC your route is defined as routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", that means that on /api/customers the WebAPI is negotiating what method to use depending on the request (GET, POST, PUT... ). Personally I'm not a fan of this but this is the easiest way to start, if you want more MVC approach the default route should be routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" that way your current url will work. more on that http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

I would like to suggest that you use some REST plugin for your browser to test API-s because you will be able to easier pinpoint the error.

Also it's not recommended to send the parameters directly to your method, you should prevalidate them see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Good luck on learning ;)
Here is a good link to start http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api